# does my jquery need a document ready with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, requirejs

Anyone got any thoughts as to whether or not you need to use a document ready with require.js? I mean if you call the js at the bottom of the page and your main.js has dependancies then surely the js won't be executed until all the necessary code is loaded anyway?

Comment: If your JavaScript code is at the very bottom of your HTML document, then no you don't need a `$(document).ready()` call.

Comment: RequireJS can take care of itself. You don't need to handle the document readiness yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> call the js at the bottom of the page

Yes, in that case you can leave out `$(document).ready` - the document is loaded right until before the end of the page.

> surely the js won't be executed until all the necessary code is loaded anyway?

No. Never rely on such timing assumptions. Always declare your dependencies - it won't slow down your code when they are already loaded, but it will prevent it from failing if they're not.